# A way to open pdf files with Reader in Texmaker on Windows 10

Tags: pdf, texmaker, windows, viewers

How can I open the generated pdf files with the [Windows Reader-App](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/apps/reader/9wzdncrfhwg5)? I am using Texmaker 4.5 and Windows 10.

What is the syntax for the "External Viewer" field so any new pdf gets opened with Reader?